# Does <algorithm> include <cmath>?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, std

The following program compiles correctly:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    return int(log(23.f));

}
```

(under g++ 4.9.2 with the flag `-std=c++11`)

The code uses the function `log`, which is defined on `<cmath>`. However, it does not include the header `<cmath>`, only the header `<algorithm>`. Why is it that `g++` doesn't give any warnings, and compiles the code correctly?

Comment: Any C++ header can include any other, but does not have to.  It appears that on your system, `<algorithm>` needs `<cmath>`.  That's fine, but don't rely on it.  Other systems may not do that and your code won't compile on those other systems.  And the compiler on those other systems is perfectly correct not to compile what your compiler is equally correct to compile.  IWYU: Include What You Use.

Comment: BTW `cmath` defines `std::log`. `log` is likely coming from the `cmath` implementation including `math.h`.

Comment: … or something else including `<math.h>`, even without bringing in `<cmath>`. I'm not sure that this is conforming, but it is the status quo. Define standard C library names in the global namespace at your own peril.

Comment: @Potatoswatter <math.h> includes <cmath> (according to [res.on.headers]/3).

Comment: @Columbo There may exist a different header within the implementation by the name of `<math.h>`, or which in any case declares `::log`. The C++ standard library is usually built atop preexisting, standalone components.

Comment: @Columbo The normative text seems to require what you say, but it's verging on ambiguity and §D.5/3 (not normative) seems to imply that `<math.h>` does not guarantee availability of `std::log`. In practice, it's unavailable in either GCC or Clang, so it seems the standard may be defective.

Comment: @Potatoswatter AFAICS §D.5/3 is 1. not normative 2. suboptimally worded. Also, I believe this is a corner-case that implementations assuredly didn't yet "discover".

Comment: @Columbo, what specifically are you referring to in _"I believe this is a corner case"_? Implementations have been dealing with this issue for decades, there is little left for them to discover. [res.on.headers] says **"as described in 17.6.1.2."** which refers to D.5, which says `<math.h>` declares `::log` but it's unspecified whether that is done via `#include <cmath>` or other means. It definitely does not require it to declare `std::log`, that was the resolution of http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#456

Comment: @JonathanWakely well.. I was horribly wrong then, nevermind :o)

Comment: @fonini, just to add some details, in C++11 mode GCC's `<algorithm>` includes `<random>` because `std::shuffle()` uses `std::uniform_int_distribution`, and `<random>` includes a number of headers including `<cmath>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the C++11 standard, [res.on.headers]/1 states that

> A C++ header may include other C++ headers. A C++ header shall provide
> the declarations and definitions that appear in its synopsis. **A C++
> header shown in its synopsis as including other C++ headers shall
> provide the declarations and definitions that appear in the synopses
> of those other headers.**

Now consider [algorithms.general]/2:

> #### Header `<algorithm>` synopsis
>
> ```
> #include <initializer_list>
>
> namespace std {
>   // ......
> ```

`<cmath>` isn't listed and clearly not included in `<initializer_list>`. Thus your program is not guaranteed to compile on a standard-conforming implementation. One should never rely on "implicit inclusion" - the general guideline is to include every header from which an entity is used.
Exceptions are e.g. `<iostream>` including `<ostream>`, which is guaranteed since C++11.

Answer (score 9):

According to the standard, some headers do include others. As an example, `<cinttypes>` includes `<cstdint>`. See the **Includes** section [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cinttypes). With respect to `<algorithm>`, there is no such statement as to which other headers it should include (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm)). So, the conclusion is, `<algorithm>` is not required to include `<cmath>`, and your example code is not portable. It may fail to compile on other C++ implementations.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question:

> Why is it that g++ doesn't give any warnings, and compiles the code correctly?

Because C++ implementations aren't required to and it's actually quite difficult to implement this warning given the way `#include` works. [Attempts](https://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/) have been made, but there are problems that haven't been entirely addressed.

---

Moving to a [different model](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html) can enable this kind of checking. However, in the interests of backwards compatibility and allowing the easiest possible transition the 'modularizations' of the standard library I've used happen to explicitly allow code that previously depended on indirect includes to continue to work.

You can see this, for example, in libc++'s [module map](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/module.modulemap); Those `export *` lines declare "any modules imported by this module are also exported." Which is to say, a module std.algorithm that imports a module std.cmath also exports, so anyone that imports std.algorithm also gets access to std.cmath.

For new code it would be very nice if these 'legacy exports' could be turned off, but for pre-existing large projects it is very nice to be able to just flip on -fmodules and have the project work with no changes.

---

Using clang's implementation of modules with libc++, and modifying the module map file to remove the non-portable, indirect include behavior, clang reports such errors like:

> main.cpp:5:16: error: declaration of 'log' must be imported from module 'Darwin.C.math' before it is required
>
> ```
> return int(log(23.f));
>            ^
> ```
>
> /usr/include/math.h:387:15: note: previous declaration is here
>
> ```
> extern double log(double);  
>               ^
> ```
>
> 1 error generated.

libc++ `<algorithm>` doesn't include `<cmath>`, so I used `<random>` instead. Otherwise the source that produced the above is the same as what you show.